# use skip and limit to iterate over cursor multiple time

Tags: mongodb, database-cursor

Can I use skip and limit multiple time to get partial result from cursor ?

```
cursor.skip(0).limit(100).toArray()
.then((docs)=>{
    
    return cursor.skip(100).limit(100).toArray();
})
```

I get following error:

> MongoCursorInUseError: Cursor is already initialized

Comment: no, no one can.

Comment: even when I call rewind between calls?

Comment: Rewind will return a clone of uninitialised cursor with closed session. It will just make another call to the database.